# Jquery add href tag when mouse is over and remove when mouse leave

Tags: jquery, html

Hi im using jquery i want to add a href tag but just when mouse is on .field-item.eve or .fiend-item.odd i try :hover but y cant remove href, i have this code:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-palabras-clave field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix">
<div class="field-label">Tags:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">shoes
            <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item odd">tennis
            <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to add this:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-palabras-clave field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix">
<div class="field-label">Tags:</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <a href="search/shoes">
            <div class="field-item even">shoes
                <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="search/tennis">
            <div class="field-item odd">tennis
                <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
jQuery('.field.field-name-field-palabras-clave.field-type-text.field-label-inline.clearfix .field-items .field-item').hover(function(){
var link = jQuery(this).text().trim(); 
jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="search/'+ link +'"></a>');
});
```

But i cant remove href when mouse leave .field-item element, could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('.field.field-name-field-palabras-clave.field-type-text.field-label-inline.clearfix .field-items .field-item').mouseenter(function() {
  var link = jQuery(this).text().trim();
  jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="search/' + link + '"></a>');
}).mouseleave(function() {
  var link = jQuery(this).text().trim();
  jQuery(this).unwrap(jQuery(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field field-name-field-palabras-clave field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix">
  <div class="field-label">Tags:</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">shoes
      <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">tennis
      <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

1. Use [.mouseenter()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

2. Use [.mouseleave()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse leaves an element, or trigger that handler on an element.